# Round off Decimals(Price) to .50 or whole numbers. C# winforms

Tags: c#, algorithm, winforms, math

Hi guys my item prices in the system are generated by the system and i would like to round it up.

Like this: 1.01 to 1.49 will be 1.50 and 1.51 to 1.99 will be 2.00

Examples: 5.56 -> 6.00 and 5.32 -> 5.50

How can i achieve this? Thank you.

Comment: [`Math.Round`?](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.round(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @DanielPark No, not `Math.Round`, because that's for rounding, which "rounding up" in this question isn't.

Comment: @hvd Yes sir that is my question. I wonder my people are downvoting my question?

Comment: @StudentDev people are down-voting because this is very much a homework-type question that is quite trivial if you apply a little bit of thinking.

Comment: I see. thank you sir!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rounding up is done using [`Math.Ceiling`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.ceiling(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

Applying the method directly would round up to the nearest dollar. The trick to rounding to the nearest 50 cents is to double the price, take its ceiling, and returning half of the result:

```
decimal roundedToFiftyCents = Math.Ceiling(2 * originalPrice) / 2;
```

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/pc1Rmf)